# Installing a 32-bit extended stored procedure on SQL Server 2008 (64-bit)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a proprietary system running against SQL Server 2000. As part of that system, there are several extended stored procedures. For a while now, I've been using a separate server, updated once a month, to run financial reports from. I copied the DLL that defined the xsp over to the separate server, and it worked fine.

However, now we're trying to copy it over to SQL Server 2008 running on a 64-bit box. I can add it in SQL Server Management Studio, but when I try to run it, I get an error saying it can't load the DLL, because "Reason: 193(%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)." Is this because I don't have the proper support DLLs loaded, or what? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can. 32 bit dlls can not be loaded in 64 bir processes. Either install 32  bit SQL Server, or get an update to your software.